# link in string of asp.net MVC 3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working in asp.net MVC 3 application with Razor view.

I have string where I need to add a link in it like this:

```
var closingMsg = "Thank you for submitting your dispute. If you wish, you may <a href='<%= Url.Action('Index', 'Product') %>purchase our SMS alert service</a> for immediate notification of any creditor response or request.";
```

But it is giving error.

Please suggest how to do it using href or HTML.actionLink. I need to apply styles to link as well.

Comment: Could you show code of your view

Comment: You don't provide enough information to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor uses `@` rather than `<% %>`

So it would be like this

```
<a href='@Url.Action('Index', 'Product')...
```

This is quite fundamental and would recommend you take some beginner tutorials to familiarize yourself with the basics.